# While upgrading the package, getting the message “You are not allowed to update Quick Action field Type”

Tags: managed-package, metadata, quickaction, upgrade

While upgrading the older version package to the newer version we are facing an issue as “You are not allowed to update Quick Action field Type”.
In the newer version, we have modified the Type of a quick action from  ‘VisualforcePage’ to ‘LightningComponent’. It had been working for all package upgrades but stopped working recently.

We checked with Salesforce support, and have received the following feedback:

> “You cannot edit the quick action type via SFDX or UI from summer 21
> release, neither you can deprecate a quick action from your managed
> package. It was a bug which was allowed to change the type via SFDX
> but it has been fixed in SU'21 release.”

We have updated the quick action type in Feb 2020, and now in the summer 21 release, we are facing this issue while upgrading the package on client org.

Is anyone else facing a similar issue? A lot of the customers will need to upgrade their packages, and we were wondering if there’s a workaround or a solution to get past this.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: It sounds like support said it: It worked previously due to taking advantage of a bug and now it won't work (changing type on existing quick action). Or are you saying you can't upgrade the quick action at all? If it's just the type, any reason why creating a different quick action wouldn't be sufficient?

Comment: @KrisGoncalves Yes, Before summer21 it's working and we are able to upgrade most of the client org. But some of the client who has an older version of the package which is quick action type is VF page now we will not able to upgrade that client to the latest package. Also As salesforce support mentioned, "neither you can deprecate a quick action from your managed package." so we can delete those from the package.